# VisualStudio LightSwitch - Unable to load data in web version of application

Tags: sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am creating application with LightSwitch where I have following the data stores:
- SharePoint 2010 list (main database) - windows authentication
- SQL database (supportive database) - static credentials

When I publish application as local app, all data from above 2 databases are shown properly and application works as it should be. 
BUT when I publish application on IIS, SharePoint list connection stops working - it simply shows red cross on the related lists. SQL database works without any issue.

I tried to remove windows authentication and inserted static credentials in application. It works properly again.

Does it mean lightswitch does not cooperate with SharePoint and does not delegate authentications? Any idea what could happen here? Statis user does not work for me - I need windows authentication.

Comment: Did you find a solution. I am having the same problem...i guess it has something to do with permissions etc.